# Remove a certain text from component

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have the next component: https://codesandbox.io/s/more-ant-design-demo-66gtb . I want to find a possibility to remove the text `/ page` from the input what changes the number of items per page, but i didn't find a way to do this. Who knows how to change that text?

Comment: "I want to find a possibility to remove the text / page from the input what changes the number of items per page"...could you please explain little more? I can't see text /page in sandbox.

Comment: @Sandy He's referring to the items per page dropdown text

Comment: Oops...my screen was small. Now I see that :(

Comment: I only see a prop `showSizeChanger` to completely disable it, but nothing in the way to define other classes for these elements. Hacky way is to write your own CSS and target those elements and override the content.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say to use

> itemRender

- To customize item's innerHTML
  (page, type: 'page' | 'prev' | 'next', originalElement) => React.ReactNode

> Go

[here](https://ant.design/components/pagination/)